# How To Extract Three Letters Followed By Five Digits Using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following dataframe in Python:

abc12345

abc1234

abc1324.

How do I extract only the ones that have three letters followed by five digits?

The desired result would be:

abc12345.

```
df.column.str.extract('[^0-9](\d\d\d\d\d)$')
```

I think this works, but is there any better way to modify (\d\d\d\d\d) ?
What if I had like 30 digits. Then I'll have to type \d 30 times, which is inefficient.

Comment: `r'[^0-9]{3}(\d{30})'` captures 30 digits after 3 non-digits. use `{ }` to specify an exact number of instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
'[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{5}'
```

If the strings don't include capital letters this can reduce to:

```
'[a-z]{3}\d{5}'
```

Change the values in the `{x}` to adjust the number of chars to capture.

Comment: Don't forget the achors `^` `$`

Answer (score 0):

Or like this following code:

'
import re

s = "abc12345"

p = re.compile(r"\d{5}")

c = p.match(s,3)

print(c.group())
'